# Limit over exponential

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to solve few questions though I know there answers I am not able to figure out the solution. I have tried to apply L'Hopital Rule as well as e^(ln) way for solving it but I am not obtaining desired answers. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you. Here are the questions with their answers

1- $\lim_{x\to\inf}(1-\frac{4}{x-1})^{3x-1}$$=e^{-12}$

2-$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{2^x-x^2}{x^x-2^2}=\frac{log2-1}{log2+1}$

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a very standard limit. Note that $(1-\frac{4}{x-1})^{3x-1}=((1-\frac{1}{\frac{x-1}{4}})^{\frac{x-1}{4}})^{(3x-1)\frac{4}{x-1}}$. Can you finish from here?

For the second one just use L'Hopital rule once. To differentiate $x^x$ write it in the form $x^x=e^{xlnx}$.

Answer (score 0):

1. $(1-\frac{4}{x-1})^{3x-1}=(1-\frac{4}{x-1})^{3x-3}(1-\frac{4}{x-1})^{2}=((1-\frac{4}{x-1})^{x-1})^3(1-\frac{4}{x-1})^{2 }\to (e^{-4})^3 \cdot 1 = e^{-12}$ as $x \to \infty.$
2. What are your problems with  L'Hopital's Rule ? This rule works for $ \lim_{x\to2}\frac{2^x-x^2}{x^x-2^2}$ !

Comment: After applying L'Hopital's Rule I have $\frac{xln2-2lnx}{xlnx-2ln2}$. I am not sure how to solve own-wards?

Comment: Your derivatives are false !

Comment: Sorry, it was by mistake $\frac{2^xln2-x^2lnx}{x^xlnx-2^2ln2}$

Comment: It is still wrong !

Comment: Oh, I have realized my mistake.

Comment: $\frac{2^xln2-2x}{x^x (1+lnx)}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{2^x-x^2}{x^x-2^2}=\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{2^x-2^2-(x^2-2^2)}{x^x-x^2+x^2-2^2}=\dfrac{2^2\cdot\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{2^{x-2}-1}{x-2}-\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{x^2-2^2}{x-2}}{x^2\cdot\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{x^{x-2}-1}{x-2}+\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{x^2-2^2}{x-2}}$$

$$=\dfrac{4\ln2-(2+2)}{4\ln2+(2+2)}$$

$$\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{x^{x-2}-1}{x-2}=\dfrac{d(x^x)}{dx}_{\text{ at } x=2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use that

$$\left(1-\frac{4}{x-1}\right)^{3x-1}=\left[\left(1-\frac{4}{x-1}\right)^{\frac{x-1}{4}}\right]^{\frac{4(3x-1)}{z-1}}$$

and by $x=2+t, \quad t \to 0$

$$\frac{2^x-x^2}{x^x-2^2}=\frac{2^{t+2}-(t+2)^2}{(t+2)^{t+2}-2^2}=\frac{4\cdot 2^{t}-4+4-(t+2)^2}{(t+2)^{t+2}-4}=$$

$$=\left(4\cdot\frac{ 2^{t}-1}{t}+\frac{4-(t+2)^2}{t}\right)\frac{t}{(t+2)^{t+2}-4}\to\frac{4\log 2-4}{4\log 2+4}=\frac{\log 2-1}{\log 2+1}$$

indeed

$$\frac{(t+2)^{t+2}-4}{t}=\frac{e^{(t+2)\log(t+2)}-4}{t}=\frac{e^{2\log(t+2)}\cdot e^{t\log(t+2)}-e^{2\log(t+2)}+e^{2\log(t+2)}-4}{t}=$$

$$=(t+2)^2\frac{e^{t\log(t+2)}-1}{t\log(t+2)}\frac{t\log(t+2)}{t}+\frac{(t+2)^2-4}{t} \to4\log 2+4$$